# Clickable dropdowns - How do they work?

Tags: css

On my current project's theme there is a clickable dropdown-menu that opens, well.. when you click it.
[The website](http://www.wein-partner.at/wp/) has a purchased theme from themeforest with a couple of required plugins, so I don't know whether a plugin is responsible for this or not.

Yes, I know this site runs WooCommerce which is sort of shunned by this community, however I want to implement this sort of feature into my private WordPress homepage I'm about to build next month.

The dropdown-menu I'm talking about is when you click the "% items" on the right side
[image: The dropdown-menu and relevant points]

I'm really curious on how to make this work. Javascript is required, isn't it?
As normal dropdowns work via repositioning the menu via ":hover" or simply overwrite a "display:none" with a "display:block".

Thanks for any help with this topic!

**edit01:** Here's the current status:
[image: current status]
site_template.php - should be completed
css has been added into the corresponding css-file
dropdown.js has been created and the code has been added
implementation of dropdown.js into site_template.php done

However I still feel like I'm missing something JS-wise...

**edit02:** I solved the problem with Google and the information provided here.
Summary:

- I implemented jQuery.js from Google in the head of my
  site_template.php.
- I copied the code provided here into my dropdown.js.
- I changed the provided CSS slightly to fit my exact situation.

Now it works as intended and opens as soon as I click the `<a>`-Element I specified for said purpose.

Comment: If you feel like rolling your own: the `:checked` pseudoclass lets you have CSS depending on whether a checkbox is checked, even when the checking/unchecking is done with a `<label>`; there's also a `:target` pseudoclass that matches if the`#fragment` is targeted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you will need both JS and CSS to get that to work:

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
        $('div.dropdown').toggleClass("open");
        event.preventDefault();
    })

})
```

**CSS:**

```
div.dropdown {
      display: none;
    }
.open > .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown">

  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">% items</a>

  <div class="dropdown-menu"><!-- items dropdown--></div>

</div>
```

If you have trouble enqueuing scripts or implementing the code, just comment.

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try it out as soon as I get to work tomorrow :)

Comment: Yeah, the community here is amazing. In terms of WooCommerce.. not so much. But in terms of Wordpress.. damn.

Comment: I've added some info about the current status on edit01.
Seems like I'm still missing something.. but what?

Comment: I just realized. The variables aren't defined yet. So that's what seemed off to me. :)